# Can I add search paths for files included with double quotes using Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c-preprocessor

Can I add search paths for files included with double quotes using Clang?

For example, suppose I have this structure:

```
project
|
|__ src
|   |
|   |_ main.cpp
|
|__ include
    |
    |_ lib.h
```

And in `main.cpp`:

```
#include "lib.h"
```

How can I allow `main.cpp` to find `lib.h` *without* moving my files around?

Comment: Use "-I dir" on compiler args

Comment: adding to what stark said, you might want to consider using build tools like cmake or gnu autotools (in cmake you can add `include_directories(include/)`)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Clang command line argument reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-iquote-directory), `-iquote<directory>` can be used to add directories to the quote include search path.